# NSNotificationCenter slow?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I've not ever used NSNotificationCenter before but I have a project that I'm reading/parsing XML from the AppDelegate which then sends a notification to a ViewController that it needs to reloadData in the tableview. From what I've seen so far, the XML parsing ends and updates an NSMutableArray and logs (NSLog) that it's complete. Several seconds later the notification is fired and the tableView is reloaded. Is that normal for NSNotificationCenter? Is there a way to set the interval at which it checks/sends messages?

```
AppDelegate.m
________________________

NSLog(@"Successful");

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateRoot" object:nil];



TableViewController.m
________________________

viewDidLoad:
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateView:) name:@"updateRoot" object:nil];


...

- (void)updateView:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.tableView reloadData]; 

    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any delay, since the notificationcenter is built on the observer pattern. It doesn't *poll* for information, the center *pushes* them.

Comment: thanks, on further analysis it appears as though it's not the notification but the table reloadData

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happens on my app, it takes about 10 seconds to transmit data from one framework to another, wonder to know if there is a way to speed it up...